# Can you set a Shiny Dashboard box width to 1.5?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny Dashboard that has 8 boxes on one row. To fit them on one row, I would need to set the width to 1.5 (out of 12).

When I do this, each box takes up an entire row :

```
fluidRow(
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot5", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot6", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot7", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot8", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot9", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot10", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Sample Flow", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot11", height = 150)),
  box(width = 1.5, title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black", dygraphOutput("plot12", height = 150))
),
```

Is there any way to fit 8 boxes on one row, filling the window?

Comment: Are you sure you can set a float point to width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the boxes in your browser, they're each wrapped in `col-sm-6` classes. So if you change the `col-sm-6` width to 12.5% (i.e., 100% / number of elements), they should all fit on one row. You might want to assign it a specific `id` instead of modifying the whole class if you have a more complex app, but for this example just changing the class itself should be fine. For more information about styling Shiny with css (and the syntax that's used here, with `tags$head` etc.), see [here.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            HTML('
            .col-sm-6 {
                width: 12.5%;
            }
            ')
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        box(title = "Sample Flow", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Sample Flow", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Sample Flow", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Sample Flow", background = "black"),
        box(title = "Last 24 Hrs", background = "black"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I would do that but I need a row of 12 and a row of 8.